# Javascript or Jquery store collection of items

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my MVC web app I have a feature where I need to store several different types of actions and a key value pair.

For example:
having a link:

```
<a class="downloadIcon" ajax-data-type="download" ajax-machineId="23" ajax-packageId="2343M324HDFHD">Download</a>
```

When someone clicked a link above, a download would start and that download link would be hidden or removed. Once a download is complete a new link would be created for "Install" option in place of the download icon. Like so:

```
<a class="installIcon" ajax-data-type="install" ajax-machineId="23" ajax-packageId="2343M324HDFHD">Install</a>
```

So I would have to remember the following items:

```
ajax-data-type => Download, Install, Uninstlall, Enable, Disable
ajax-data-machineId => int
ajax-data-packageId => int
```

This functionality would ensure that (for example) when a download is "downloading" BUT NOT done, and a user refreshes his/her browser, the download link would NOT display again (since the download was already initiated). However once installed (that functionality is already done and I get a response from server) and then later uninstalled I would have to display "download" link again etc.

Would I use a cookie for this? any ideas, help would be greatly appreciated.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use localStorage for this kind of thing.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Essentially, you can just add variables to localStorage, and it will save them for future visits.

So, for example:

On downloading: `localStorage.state = 'downloading'`

On done: `localStorage.state = 'done'`

on page load:

```
if(localStorage.state)
    $(".downloadIcon").hide()
if(localStorage.state == 'done')
    $(".installIcon").show()
```

Answer (score 0):

if you change html like below

```
<a class="installIcon" data-ajax-type="install" data-ajax-machineId="23" data-ajax-packageId="2343M324HDFHD">Install</a>
```

You can use something like `$("a.installIcon").data("ajax-type")` to get the data you want.
Also you can change the value of each data like `$("a.installIcon").data("ajax-type","Disable")`